# Track issue-related comments like "// fixes #123" in Visual Studio, similar to task list

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

We use an issue tracker (Redmine) for our software tasks/bugs and often mark the fixes/implementations with a comment like this:

```
// fixes #1234: changed this and that
```

Or we also mark code locations which cause a certain bug like this:

```
// causes #2345
```

Now, I am looking for a tool which can automatically track those issue-related comments in all files in the current solution and present them in a list or tree. This is similar to the task list which scans the files for comments with `// TODO` or `// HACK`. Unfortunately, it is not possible to define a new task category with just `#` as identifier because this character is not allowed.

Does anyone know of such a functionality, addon, or tool for VS2010 or VS2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally a feature provided by whatever issue tracking software you use rather than a function of Visual Studio.  [Codebase HQ](http://www.codebasehq.com/) for example scans code (on commit) for speciially formatted comments that it is configured to recognise and groups the code change/commit to the record of the issue.  It's web-based.

Axosoft OnTime provide a plugin for Visual Studio which allow you to work with your issues directly within the IDE.

See: http://www.axosoft.com/ontime/visual_studio_plugin

Failing that, if you only want to track bug causes *between* commits while you're working, then the inbuild tracker might be of use after all...

Add a tag to track with to Visual Studios configuration (I've added the CausesBug token)...

[image: Add a new token to the task list options]

Then add the token in amongst your code:

```
  public override bool IsApproved {
     get
     {
        // CausesBug: 1234
        return this.IsEnabled;
     }
     set { this.IsEnabled = value; }    
  }
```

Then each item gets listed in the Task List, displaying location in source, until you can ammend, and then say you fixed the issue in your commit, in turn getting picked up by your issue tracker.

[image]

Comment: I know and use a similar feature in Redmine. Redmine also parses the commit message for issue IDs and associates the revision with the issue. But that is not what I am looking for. If you read my question closely, you will understand that I am looking for a way to automatically find comments *in the code* containing an issue ID like 'causes #123'. These comments/code locations should then be listed somewhere in VS, so that I can easily look up the code locations which have caused issue #123. This makes sense if an issue has been analyzed, but not yet fixed.

Comment: After re-reading your answer, I understand that Codebase HQ does something like that. Redmine only parses the commit message, while Codebase HQ seems to parse the code as well. This is nice, but I do not want to be restricted to a certain issue tracker. I would rather have a plugin for VS2010 which parses the code and lists all matching code locations/comments. Anyway, thanks for you answer.

Comment: If you want to use a issue tracker agnostic tool, then the built in task list might be suitable after all?  At least you can track them within the IDE.  I've edited the question with some more details.

Comment: Yes, this is an option, but a poor one unfortunately because it will be mixed with all my TODOs. :) Anyway, it seems like this is the only way - at least nobody proposed another solution. I was hoping for proposals for plugins which do just that, but obviously there is none.